# How can I repair my vinyl skirting?

Tags: damage, siding

After some gusty storms put my vinyl skirting into disrepair, I need some advice on how to secure the guide that runs along the ground that the skirting sits in. The ground is not level and not flat so I am short on ideas. Right now it is held in place by .5"x6" spikes but the wind came with rain and the spikes just moved sideways. The house is 72' long and from 2-4' tall. That is a lot of surface area for the wind to act on so the solution has to be rather strong. Any ideas?

**Note:** I dont have enough rep to make my own tags and cant find any, more appropriate tags

Comment: WHat material is the siding?  Side note, added skirting as a tag although siding is an appropriate choice.

Comment: @allindal edited to note that it is vinyl

Comment: @Bobnix, "held in place by .5"x6" spikes" does that mean 1/2inch long nails @ 6inch centres? Can you see or workout where the vertical timber wall studs are (normally on 16inch centers)?

Comment: is any of it the vented style or is it all solid vinyl?  You could get some pressure treated 2x4's and lay them flat and screwed the track to that.